# Aurelia - bind only once showing the title in repeater

Tags: aurelia

I have a list of users, every users have some roles. In aurelia html file I want to categorize the users. The incoming data has all the users chronologically by roles.

So basically, if the user has a role1, show section title ROLE1 and list those users, then show ROLE2 and list those users.

I tried to use this:

```
<p if.bind="user.role1">ROLE1</p>
<p if.bind="user.role2">ROLE2</p>
```

and here is my full code:

```
    <template repeat.for="user of users">

<p if.bind="user.role1">ROLE1</p>
                      <p if.bind="user.role2">ROLE2</p>
                                            <checkbox-input label="${user.name}" checked-value.two-way="user['selected']"></checkbox-input>
                                        </template>
```

The problem is, that the titles ROLE1 or ROLE2 are showing above each user as this in a repeater, but I need to show them only once. I tried to use also if.bind.one-time but that works not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it different way - I used the same repeaters 2 times. The titles I put above the repeater and inside the checkboxes I used if.bind="user.role1" or role2 for the second one. This way it works, however I wanted to solve it easier, but finally this works.

```
<p>ROLE1</p>
<template repeat.for="user of users">
                                            <checkbox-input if.bind="user.role1" label="${user.name}" checked-value.two-way="user['selected']"></checkbox-input>
                                        </template>

<p>ROLE2</p>
<template repeat.for="user of users">
                                            <checkbox-input if.bind="user.role2" label="${user.name}" checked-value.two-way="user['selected']"></checkbox-input>
                                        </template>
```